# I want to reload the App IOS/ Android after coming back from offline to online - Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I need to reload my Xamarin IOS / Android app after turn on my internet connection (turn on wifi or mobile data)

I have code to check whether internet is available or not

**Just I need to refresh App page**

More info

App shell contains

```
 <TabBar>
        <Tab Title="Home" Route="Home">
            <Tab.Icon>
                <FontImageSource 
                            x:Name="home"
                             Glyph="&#xe065;"
                             FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeSolid}"
                             Size="20" 
                            />
            </Tab.Icon>
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Home}" />
        </Tab>
....................
</TabBar>
```

C# Code

```
 private void Connectivity_ConnectivityChanged(object sender, ConnectivityChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            IsInternetNotAvailable = e.NetworkAccess != NetworkAccess.Internet;
           
            if (IsInternetNotAvailable == false)
            {

            }
     }
```

Comment: 'Application.Current.MainPage = new AppShell();' I tried this code it works but the problem is, it is loading new pages top of the current pages

Comment: you can create a new activity and destroy the previous activity or you can create a new App Instance in main Activity

Comment: @RonakShethia any reference link please?

Comment: I dont have any reference for that but u can follow this, create a action App.cs, implement that action in Main Activity and implement a method on action which creates a new object of your App.cs    here is what will create a new instance   LoadApplication(new App());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center) to publish a message when the network changed:

```
private void Connectivity_ConnectivityChanged(object sender, ConnectivityChangedEventArgs e)
{
    IsInternetNotAvailable = e.NetworkAccess != NetworkAccess.Internet;

    if (IsInternetNotAvailable == false)
    {
        MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage, string>(this, "NetWorkChange", "NotAvailable");
    }
}
```

And subscribe to the message in all other page you need to update. Unsubscribe it in `OnDisappearing` method:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPage, string>(this, "Hi", async (sender, arg) =>
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Message received", "arg=" + arg, "OK");

        if (arg == "NotAvailable")
        {

        }
        else
        {
          
        }
    });
}

protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    base.OnDisappearing();

    MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<MainPage, string>(this, "Hi");
}
```